# Print specific value in Realm array using Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I am new to Realm / Swift and trying to do simple prints. I have this simple code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Click
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var testclick : Results<Click>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func clickButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        do {

            let testclick = try Realm().objects(Click).filter("id == 1")

            // let totalclicks = testclick.totalclicks

            print(testclick)

        } catch {}

        let click = Click()
        click.id = 1
        click.totalclicks = 5
        click.name = "C. Boutrup"

        do {
            let realm = try Realm()

            try realm.write {
                realm.add(click, update: true)
            }

        } catch {}

    }
}
```

Result of print(testclick) is correct:

```
Results<Click> (
    [0] Click {
        id = 1;
        name = C. Boutrup;
        totalclicks = 5;
    }
)
```

but how do I only get the value of for example totalclicks? Tried with let totalclicks = testclick.totalclicks but I won't work.

When writing to Realm I want the total value of totalclicks to be total clicks from the Results + 1, something like click.totalclicks = totalclicks + 1. What is the correct code for that?

Thanks in advance :-)

Update:

Both answers was resulting in great work, and you can se both solutions here:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Click
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func clickButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        //initialize your realm
        let realm = try! Realm()

        //check if there is a Click with id == 1
        if let clickWithId1 = realm.objects(Click).filter("id == 1").first {
            do {
                //if there is a Click with id == 1, increment its totalclicks by 1 and update it

                try realm.write {
                    clickWithId1.totalclicks += 1
                    realm.add(clickWithId1, update: true)
                }

            } catch {}
        } else {  // if there is no Click with id == 1, create it and add it to realm
            let click = Click()
            click.id = 1
            click.totalclicks = 5
            click.name = "C. Boutrup"

            do {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(click, update: true)
                }

            } catch {}
        }
    }
}
```

Second solution:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Click
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var testclick : Results<Click>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func clickButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        do {

            // let testclick = try Realm().objects(Click).filter("id == 1")
            // let name = testclick.name
            // print(testclick)

            // Get a list of objects back out of Realm
            let results = try Realm().objects(Click).filter("id == 1")

            // Access the first object from the list (results[0] would also work)
            let testclick = results.first

            // Print its total clicks value
            print(testclick!.totalclicks)

            // trying
            let myclicks = testclick!.totalclicks

            let click = Click()
            click.id = 1
            click.totalclicks = myclicks + 1

            print(click.totalclicks)

            let realm = try Realm()

            try realm.write {
                realm.add(click, update: true)
            }

        } catch {}

    }
}
```

Comment: Won't work how? Because it's defined inside the try and you try to use it outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this if the 'id' property is your object's primary key:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Click
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func clickButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        //initialize your realm
        let realm = try! Realm()

        //check if there is a Click with id == 1
        if let clickWithId1 = realm.objects(Click).filter("id == 1").first {
            do {
                //if there is a Click with id == 1, increment its totalclicks by 1 and update it

                try realm.write {
                    clickWithId1.totalclicks += 1
                    realm.add(clickWithId1, update: true)
                }

            } catch {}
        } else {  // if there is no Click with id == 1, create it and add it to realm
            let click = Click()
            click.id = 1
            click.totalclicks = 5
            click.name = "C. Boutrup"

            do {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(click, update: true)
                }

            } catch {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggest, and it was Build Succeeded, but get error when clicking on the button: 2016-02-10 09:49:58.798 Click[4532:918521] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

Comment: Moved the line we incremented the totalclicks in to the write block, can you try again now

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `testclick` will be a `Results` object, which will be an array of zero or more results for your query.

To actually access your `Click` object, you need to first get it out of the results object.

```
// Get a list of objects back out of Realm
let results = try Realm().objects(Click).filter("id == 1")

// Access the first object from the list (results[0] would also work)
let testclick = results.first

// Print its total clicks value 
print(testclick.totalclicks)
```

Let me know if you need any more clarification! :)